# How to Delete html tags form responseJson in react native?

Tags: react-native, fetch

How can I delete html tags? I need to show description, but html tag not support in react native.

json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 73,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "status": "publish",
    "description": "<p>hello</p>\n",
    ...
```

codes:

```
componentDidMount(){
  return fetch('example.com/testttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt')
  .then((response)=>response.json()).
  then((responseJson)=>{
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});
    this.setState({
      isLoading:false,
      dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson)
    });
  }).catch((error)=>console.error(error));
}
```

and listView:

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={ (rowData)=>
                <View style={{width:'100%',height:40}}>
                  <View style={{marginTop:5,marginBottom:5}}>
                    <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{rowData.description}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
          }
      />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: @SamiHult I don't know how can I use replace for this case.

Comment: @SamiHult any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping html tags is not a trivial problem. Many issues have been discussed in the question [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript).

In my opinion, the best approach would be to use a library like [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags). Then your code would look like:

```
<Text>{striptags(rowData.description)}</Text>
```

Another, more naive implementation could use `String.prototype.replace`:

```
<Text>{rowData.description.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')}</Text>
```